# Dynamics AX cross-company query with VendTrans and Global Address Book

Tags: view, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I'm trying to create a simple cross-company query between VendTrans and VendTable. We have Global Address Book enabled so some entries are shared across companies. If I was writing SQL, it would look like:

```
select vtxn.Voucher, vtxn.TransDate, vt.AccountNum, vt.Name
from dbo.vendtrans vtxn
join dbo.vendtable vt on vtxn.accountnum = vt.accountnum 
    and vt.dataareaid in (vtxn.dataareaid, 'shr')
```

The problem I am encountering is that because of the global address book, I am getting no results from the query and view defined below. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

```
QUERY #spTestQuery
  PROPERTIES
    Name                #spTestQuery
    UserUpdate          #No
    Version             #524
    NextUniqueId        #1008
    AllowCrossCompany   #Yes
  ENDPROPERTIES

  METHODS
    Version: 3
    SOURCE #classDeclaration
      #public class QueryRun extends ObjectRun
      #{
      #}
    ENDSOURCE
  ENDMETHODS
  BLOCKS
    BLOCK #LedgerJournalTrans
      PROPERTIES
        Name                #LedgerJournalTrans_1
        Table               #LedgerJournalTrans
        UniqueId            #1000
        FirstFast           #Yes
        AllowAdd            #No fields
      ENDPROPERTIES

      FIELDLIST
        PROPERTIES
          Dynamic             #No
        ENDPROPERTIES

        FIELD #BankChequeNum
        FIELD #TransDate
      ENDFIELDLIST
      SORTING
      ENDSORTING
      LINES
        LINE #BankChequeNum
        PROPERTIES
          Name                #BankChequeNum
          Table               #LedgerJournalTrans
          Field               #BankChequeNum
          Value               #> 0
        ENDPROPERTIES

      ENDLINES
      BLOCKS
        BLOCK #VendTrans
          PROPERTIES
            Name                #VendTrans_1
            Table               #VendTrans
            UniqueId            #1003
            AllowAdd            #No fields
            FetchMode           #1:1
            Relations           #Yes
          ENDPROPERTIES

          FIELDLIST
            PROPERTIES
              Dynamic             #No
            ENDPROPERTIES

            FIELD #AccountNum
            FIELD #LastSettleVoucher
          ENDFIELDLIST
          SORTING
          ENDSORTING
          LINES
          ENDLINES
          BLOCKS
            BLOCK #VendTable
              PROPERTIES
                Name                #VendTable_1
                Table               #VendTable
                UniqueId            #1004
                Relations           #Yes
                Enabled             #No
              ENDPROPERTIES

              FIELDLIST
                PROPERTIES
                  Dynamic             #No
                ENDPROPERTIES

                FIELD #Name
                FIELD #AccountNum
              ENDFIELDLIST
              SORTING
              ENDSORTING
              LINES
              ENDLINES
              BLOCKS
              ENDBLOCKS
              ASSOCIATIONS
                ASSOCIATION
                  MASTERFIELD  #AccountNum
                  DETAILSFIELD #AccountNum
              ENDASSOCIATIONS
            ENDBLOCK
          ENDBLOCKS
          ASSOCIATIONS
            ASSOCIATION
              MASTERFIELD  #AccountNum
              DETAILSFIELD #AccountNum
          ENDASSOCIATIONS
        ENDBLOCK
        BLOCK #LedgerTrans
          PROPERTIES
            Name                #LedgerTrans_1
            Table               #LedgerTrans
            UniqueId            #1005
            AllowAdd            #No fields
            FetchMode           #1:1
            Relations           #Yes
          ENDPROPERTIES

          FIELDLIST
            PROPERTIES
              Dynamic             #No
            ENDPROPERTIES

            FIELD #AccountNum
            FIELD #Voucher
            FIELD #AmountMST
            FIELD #TransDate
            FIELD #Voucher
            FIELD #Dimension
          ENDFIELDLIST
          SORTING
          ENDSORTING
          LINES
            LINE #AccountNum
            PROPERTIES
              Name                #AccountNum
              Table               #LedgerTrans
              Field               #AccountNum
              Value               #!211000
            ENDPROPERTIES

          ENDLINES
          BLOCKS
            BLOCK #LedgerTable
              PROPERTIES
                Name                #LedgerTable_1
                Table               #LedgerTable
                UniqueId            #1006
                AllowAdd            #No fields
                Relations           #Yes
              ENDPROPERTIES

              FIELDLIST
                PROPERTIES
                  Dynamic             #No
                ENDPROPERTIES

                FIELD #AccountName
                FIELD #AccountNum
              ENDFIELDLIST
              SORTING
              ENDSORTING
              LINES
              ENDLINES
              BLOCKS
              ENDBLOCKS
              ASSOCIATIONS
                ASSOCIATION
                  MASTERFIELD  #AccountNum
                  DETAILSFIELD #AccountNum
              ENDASSOCIATIONS
            ENDBLOCK
            BLOCK #Dimensions
              PROPERTIES
                Name                #Dimensions_1
                Table               #Dimensions
                UniqueId            #1007
                AllowAdd            #No fields
              ENDPROPERTIES

              FIELDLIST
                PROPERTIES
                  Dynamic             #No
                ENDPROPERTIES

                FIELD #Description
                FIELD #Num
                FIELD #DimensionCode
              ENDFIELDLIST
              SORTING
              ENDSORTING
              LINES
                LINE #DimensionCode
                PROPERTIES
                  Name                #DimensionCode
                  Table               #Dimensions
                  Field               #DimensionCode
                  Value               #Purpose
                ENDPROPERTIES

              ENDLINES
              BLOCKS
              ENDBLOCKS
              ASSOCIATIONS
                ASSOCIATION
                  JOINDATASOURCE #LedgerTrans_1
                  MASTERFIELD  #Dimension[3]
                  DETAILSFIELD #Num
              ENDASSOCIATIONS
            ENDBLOCK
          ENDBLOCKS
          ASSOCIATIONS
            ASSOCIATION
              MASTERFIELD  #TransDate
              DETAILSFIELD #TransDate
            ASSOCIATION
              MASTERFIELD  #Voucher
              DETAILSFIELD #Voucher
          ENDASSOCIATIONS
        ENDBLOCK
      ENDBLOCKS
      GROUPBY
      ENDGROUPBY
      ORDERBY
      ENDORDERBY
    ENDBLOCK
  ENDBLOCKS
  DEPENDENTS
    DEPENDENT
      PROPERTIES
        Name                #spTestView
        DependentType       #View
      ENDPROPERTIES

      Id 50005
  ENDDEPENDENTS
  COMPOSITEQUERIES
  ENDCOMPOSITEQUERIES
ENDQUERY

  VIEW #spVendTestView
    Id 50008
    PROPERTIES
      Name                #spVendTestView
      SaveDataPerCompany  #Yes
      Query               #spvendtest
    ENDPROPERTIES

    QUERY #Metadata
      PROPERTIES
        Name                #Metadata
        AllowCrossCompany   #Yes
      ENDPROPERTIES

      BLOCKS
      ENDBLOCKS
      QUERY #spVendTest
      ENDQUERY

    ENDQUERY

    FIELDS
      VIEWFIELD #Voucher
        Id 50001
        PROPERTIES
          Name                #Voucher
          Table               #spVendTestView
          ExtendedDataType    #Voucher
          StringSize          #25
          DataSource          #VendTrans_1
          DataField           #Voucher
        ENDPROPERTIES

      ENDVIEWFIELD

      VIEWFIELD #TransDate
        Id 50003
        PROPERTIES
          Type                #Date
          Name                #TransDate
          Table               #spVendTestView
          ExtendedDataType    #TransDate
          StringSize          #(Memo)
          DataSource          #VendTrans_1
          DataField           #TransDate
        ENDPROPERTIES

      ENDVIEWFIELD

      VIEWFIELD #AccountNum
        Id 50004
        PROPERTIES
          Name                #AccountNum
          Table               #spVendTestView
          ExtendedDataType    #VendAccount
          StringSize          #20
          DataSource          #VendTable_1
          DataField           #AccountNum
        ENDPROPERTIES

      ENDVIEWFIELD

      VIEWFIELD #Name
        Id 50002
        PROPERTIES
          Name                #Name
          Table               #spVendTestView
          ExtendedDataType    #VendName
          StringSize          #120
          DataSource          #VendTable_1
          DataField           #Name
        ENDPROPERTIES

      ENDVIEWFIELD

    ENDFIELDS
    GROUPS
    ENDGROUPS

  ENDVIEW
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see you define a query with `crosscompany` then define a view based on the query.
However the `crosscompany` on the query does not imply that the view is `crosscompany`also.

Have a look on [Cross-Company Queries for Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc621079.aspx).

Excerpt:

> In the Application Object Tree (AOT), you can build a view by dragging
>   a query node onto the Data Sources node of your view. The query could
>   have the AllowCrossCompany property set to Yes. However, this will not
>   return cross-company results from the view.
>
> To return cross-company results from a view, you need to use the
>   crossCompany keyword on the select statement that reads from the view.
>   The AllowCrossCompany setting on the view's data source query is
>   ignored in X++ select statements that read from a view.

Comment: Have tried adding setting the AllowCrossCompany to Yes under the MetaData node.

Using the following query:
    SELECT crossCompany * FROM spVendTestView

Get this error:
Using X++ to select records from a cross-company table that is owned by the form datasource is not supported.

Comment: Have you tried implementing form using the query directly? Alternatively you could use regular old style form data sources.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Code above is a query with a view defined with the query as the datasource. Not necessarily using this for a report. Either way, this should probably return something.

Comment: Maybe you trying something which is not possible?